# Replace word phrases, honoring punctuation in php

Tags: php

I have a custom php script that looks through text to find key phrases and replaces them using preg_replace, but I'm having trouble getting a clean regex for the job.

For example this sentence:

> The fox jumped over the gated fence
>   because it did not have hands to open
>   the gate.

I would want to bold all instances of `gate`, yet respect oddities like `gated`. And also preserve original capitalization too if possible.

So the end sentence would read like this:

> The fox jumped over the gated fence
>   because it did not have hands to open
>   the **gate**.

Here is the regular expression I've created myself, and you will see that it would not account for gate. because of the period following the word. And also the regex does not respect any original capitalization.

```
$description  = preg_replace("/ $keyphrase /", " <b>$keyphrase</b> ", $description, $limit);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\b'.preg_quote($keyphrase, '/').'\b/i',
    function ($matches) {
        return "<b>" . $matches[0] . "</b>";
    }, htmlspecialchars($subject));
```

You need to use word boundaries (`\b`). Do not forget to:

- Properly escape the key phrase for use in the regex expression (use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote)).
- Properly escape for HTML special characters the sentence. This is necessary assuming you're turning a text string into an HTML string. If the initial string already has HTML, **do not use regex**.

**EDIT** PHP < 5.3 must use:

```
function cb($matches) {
    return "<b>" . $matches[0] . "</b>";
};
preg_replace_callback('/\b'.preg_quote($keyphrase, '/').'\b/i', 'cb',
   htmlspecialchars($subject));
```

Comment: Hello artefacto,

Why should I avoid strings with html? Its highly likely that strings will contain divs, tables, links, and images. I can parse the images and links out and re-add them in, but the tables and divs will still be there occasionally.

h

Comment: @atwell See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Hey Art, I'm going ahead and test-running your regex and it's returning this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION. I'm out of my league when it comes to using functions to create result sets could you advise? -- maybe because I'm already within a function?

Comment: @atwell That's because you're not running PHP 5.3. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks again art. Question, how can I pass variables into the cb function without using globals? ... Reason being is because I'll define start and end codes like <i></i> and <b></b> depending on a settings I have associated with the keyphrase.

So if keyphrase 1 is setup to be bolded I would need to pass $start_tag, which has dynamically been set as <b> and $end_tag which has been set as </b>

Comment: @atwellpub See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527386/php-passing-more-than-one-argument-to-a-callback-function-using-php-5-2/3527532#3527532