# Is the 'use' keyword available for function closures pre 5.3?

Tags: php, array-map

Hell, I can't even FIND the documentation for 'use' on the PHP site (other than in the context of namespaces - nice job ambiguating a keyword BTW).

Can someone confirm that `function() use ($foo) { }` is only available in 5.3 and later? And where did you find that documented?

As an added bonus, how would you code around not being able to use 'use' (eg: with create_function($args, $funcname) as the callback for array_map())?

Comment: Just to make that clear (because I still don't understand the second question completely ;)): You can use closures with `array_map()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures are introduced in 5.3, thus `use` in conjunction with closures are also available in 5.3 or later (of course).

> As an added bonus, how would you code around not being able to use 'use' within a closure

I don't understand the question completely, but because both closures and `use` with closures comes with the same version, there is no situation, where you can not use `use` with closures. Either both, or nothing (--> <5.3)

http://php.net/functions.anonymous

[Release Notes 5.3.0](http://php.net/releases/5_3_0.php)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the 5.3 thing. How would you work around the variable scope issue if you are forced to use create_function($args, $funcname)?

Comment: You shouldn't use `create_function()`, because its based on `eval()` and (as we all know) its evil ;) However, its not directly possible for complex types (like objects and arrays) and primitive types can be simply integrated into the source, e.g. `create_function('$a, $b', 'return ' . $outsideVar . ';');`

Comment: Yes, I can't stand create_function myself. But of course you're right: simply add the scalar to the source definition string. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of closures, in a pre 5.3 world, if you want to avoid create_function() but need to bind variables from an external scope to a callback type function, wrap the function in a class, to which you pass your external variables upon instantiation.

If you do this a lot, you may find the following generic wrapper class useful (or ugly, or both as do I):

```
class GenericCallbackWrapper {
    function __construct (){
        $argIndex = 1;
        foreach(func_get_args() as $value){
            $argName = 'user' . $argIndex;
            $this->$argName = $value;
        }
    }

    public function example_strip_prefix($a){
        return substr($a, strlen($this->user1));
    }
}
```

I would actually put this in an external file (callbacks.php) and then just keep adding your callback code a public methods of this class. Obviously, this only pays dividends if you're going to do this frequently; otherwise, just create a one-off wrapper class whose constructor accepts the specific number of arguments you're looking to include.

This generic code can then be leveraged using the two-argument form for specifying a callback:

```
function get_input_field_IDs_by_prefix($prefix){
    return array_map(
        array(new GenericCallbackWrapper($prefix), 'example_strip_prefix'),
        preg_grep('/^'.$prefix.'/', array_keys($_REQUEST))
    );
}
```

The generic wrapper takes any number of arguments and adds them as member (instance) variables to the class that can then be accessed in order as $this->user1, $this->user2 etc (initial index is 1).

Hope this is of some use to someone. At some point. Maybe.

Comment: Nice code (have something similar). Note that your $argName should actually hold a parameter `&` *reference*, to mimic the `use` behaviour.